# Usage of "Point taken."

Tags: idioms

> A : B, you have to be on the pill! Because of ...
>
> B:Point taken.

So, What If It was between two close friends, like ;

> Hey John! You must take your pills regularly. Otherwise...
>
> Point taken!

Would It be grammatically correct? Even so , is it way too formal for an informal conversation? Could someone enlighten me with some examples? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Point taken** is a BrE expression meaning **I acknowledge your point**. It can be thought of as a shortened form of

> Your **point** is well **taken**.

An AmE (and BrE) equivalent would be

> **Good point!**

It is usually said when there are **multiple** views on a subject. The speaker does **not need to be in agreement** to say this and it is usually said to acknowledge an **opposite or contrasting** view to the current status.

> Commander: Our surprise attack will be at noon!
>   Soldier: But won't the enemy be able to see us then?
>   Commander: Point taken!

Comment: I am AmE and I use "point taken" regularly. I didn't know it was just BrE.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was exclusively BrE. I had only heard it used while living in the UK. Of course there will be seepage in this age of cross-media-awareness. **Point taken!**